# ESLint rule to insert an empty line between user modules and standard node modules

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-modules

Is there any ESLint rule to check the following case?

```
import foo from 'foo'
// New line should be added
import bar from './bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `padding-line-between-statements` property.

**General configuration:**

```
...
"padding-line-between-statements": [
   "error",
   { 
     "blankLine": LINEBREAK_TYPE, // "always" | "never" | "any"
     "prev": STATEMENT_TYPE, // "var" | "let" | "import" | etc...
     "next": STATEMENT_TYPE 
   }
]
...
```

LINEBREAK_TYPE: can be `"any"` or `"never"` or `"always"`

STATEMENT_TYPE: can be almost all keywords of `ecmascript`

in your case it's

```
...
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
       "error",
       { 
         "blankLine": "always",
         "prev": "import",
         "next": "import" 
       }
    ]
    ...
```